# Prove equal cardinality between two sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm preparing for a discrete math course in September and I'm trying to study on my own this summer. I've run into a bit of trouble with a practice problem I found online and can't really figure it out on my own.

Let A = set of all integers with 2 as a factor

Let B = set of all integers with 3 as a factor

Prove |A| = |B|

I understand that I have to prove a 1-1 correspondence by finding a function that maps A to B and proving bijectivity. But, I'm not sure how to find this function?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice.  For this example start by developing a more explicit representation of sets $A,B$.

Comment: You don't actually have to show a 1-1 correspondence because there is at least [one other way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write simply

$$A=2\Bbb Z:=\{...-4,-2,0,2,4,...,2m,...\}\;,\;\;B=3\Bbb Z=\{...-3,0,3,6,...,3m,...\}$$

Can you guess now a nice bijection between the above sets?

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:A\rightarrow B$ by $f(n)=\frac{3}{2}n$. This is well defined and injective. Its inverse is also clearly injective. So this defines a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea :

Take the function $\Phi$ defined by $\Phi(2^n 3^m q) = 2^m 3^n q$ (where $q$ is not dividible by $2$ or $3$) and show that it's a bijection $\Bbb N^* \to \Bbb N^*$

Then it's easy to see that the set of multiple of $2$ is in bijection with the set of multiples of $3$